# Solve systems of non-linear equations

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear

How could try to solve this system of linear equations. I made a code in R trying to solve it, that might make me suggestions please. I want to estimate $\lambda$, $\beta$ and $\alpha$.

$$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \lambda} = -\left[\frac{n}{\lambda} - \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{t_i}^2 + \frac{\alpha-1}{\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{t_i} w_i \right] = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \alpha} = \frac{n}{\alpha} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \beta} = -\left[\frac{n}{2\beta} -  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\beta + t_i} + \frac{1}{2\lambda^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\frac{1}{t_i} - \frac{t_i}{\beta^2}\right] + \frac{\alpha -1}{2\lambda\beta^{3/2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{t_i + \beta}{t_i^{1/2}}w_i\right] = 0$$

with

$$u_i=log\left( \Phi(a_{t_i})\right) , \,\,\,a_t = \frac{1}{\lambda}\left(\sqrt{\frac{t}{\beta}} - \sqrt{\frac{\beta}{t}}\right), \,\,\, w_i = \frac{\phi(a_{t_i})}{\Phi(a_{t_i})}$$

where $\phi(.)$ is pdf and $\Phi(.)$ is cdf of normal distribution standard. In the next R code $theta[1]=\lambda$, $theta[2]=\beta$ and $theta[3]=\alpha$.

```
 library(nleqslv)


f <- function(theta){

t = c(370,706,716,746,785,797,844,855,858,886,886,930,960,988,990,1000,   
1010,1016,1018,1020,1055,1085,1102,1102,1108,1115,1120,1134,1140,1199,1200,1200, 
1203,1222,1235,1238,1252,1258,1262,1269,1270,1290,1293,1300,1310,1313,1315,1330, 
1355,1390,1416,1419,1420,1420,1450,1452,1475,1478,1481,1485,1502,1505,1513,1522, 
1522,1530,1540,1560,1567,1578,1594,1602,1604,1608,1630,1642,1674,1730,1750,1750, 
1763,1768,1781,1782,1792,1820,1868,1881,1890,1893,1895,1910,1923,1940,1945,2023, 
2100,2130,2215,2268,2440)

n = length(t)

y  <- numeric(3)
at <- (1/theta[1])*(sqrt(abs(t/theta[2]))-sqrt(abs(theta[2]/t))) 
w  <- dnorm(at)/pnorm(at)

y[1] <- -(n/theta[1] - (1/theta[1])*sum(at^2) + ((theta[3] - 1)/theta[1])*sum(at*w))

y[2] <- n/theta[3] + sum(log(pnorm(at)))

y[3] <- -(n/(2*theta[2]) - sum(1/(theta[2] + t)) + (1/(2*theta[1]^2))*(sum(1/t -
t/theta[2]^2)) + (theta[3]-1)/(2*theta[1]*theta[2]^1.5)*sum((t + theta[2])*w/t^0.5))
y
}


 thetastart=c(0.310321,1336.556,1.026678)

 nleqslv(thetastart, f, method="Broyden")
```

To initialize maximization procedure for $\lambda$ and $\beta$, we used the Maximum Likelihood Estimation. My results are different from the paper. The paper show this results $\widehat{\lambda}=0.0996$, $\widehat{\beta}=2135.99$ and $\widehat{\alpha}=0.0527$.

In my case the results are: $\widehat{\lambda}=0.3039866$, $\widehat{\beta}=1350.9853662$ and $\widehat{\alpha}=0.9400624$.

thanks for your possible suggestions

The paper the reference is http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02331888.2013.846910

Please.

Comment: There is at least one typographical error in the code (`thetastar` is not defined on the last line).  If even a single minor error occurs anywhere in the specification of `f`, you will get wrong answers. However, since access to the paper is restricted, most people will be unable to check your code--nor should you expect them to.  To be fair to our readers you need to verify that you have correctly implemented the equations in your code before asking them to review it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It would be illegal placed the pdf of the paper?

Comment: Fixing the typo changes nothing: I pointed it out only as (strong) evidence of the possibility that some other error is present in the code. We are not a code review site, so without substantial changes being made to this question, it has to be closed as off topic.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That being the case, then my interest is not to review the code but can suggest some solution method using R.

Comment: OK, you are correct about that.  I will reluctantly vote to reopen.  My reluctance stems from the likelihood that although you might get good solutions *to the question as written,* they might not solve the actual problem you face (but instead would solve some corrupted version of the problem), and it also seems likely that any good solution could involve considerable work.  I view that situation as an imposition on our willing and dedicated community. There are plenty of things you could do to simplify your question and save a lot of work on the part of your readers. (-1)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree on reducing users work, and therefore why put the program in R, the system of equations is correctly written. Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: Among the things you can do before asking people to review technical code like this are (1) inspect the return code from `nleqslv` for error conditions, (2) re-run the code starting with the paper's solution to see whether it can be improved at all, (3) use alternative solution methods for `nleqslv`, (4) double-check that the data are correctly and completely entered, (5) create a small test suite for `f` to make sure it gives sensible results (and, if possible, reproduces any results given in the paper), and (6) plot the functions defined in `f` to verify they behave as expected.

Comment: What is the expression of function $l$? I didn't read the paper that you mention but it seems to me more natural to maximize the likelihood function passing the expressions of the gradient to the optimization algorithm rather than solving the system of equations that equates the gradient vector to zeros. You could write a function that returns the value of the likelihood function and try to maximize it by means of any of the methods available in the function `stats::optim`, e.g. BFGS.